# some confusion with generic types in c#

Tags: c#, generics, casting, cqrs

I'm playing with cqs a little bit and I'm trying to implement this in a class library (so there's no IOC, IServiceProvider, etc). Here is some code that I wrote:

```
public interface IQuery<TResult>
{
}

public interface IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
{
    TResult Handle(TQuery query);
}

public class Query : IQuery<bool>
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class QueryHandler : IQueryHandler<Query, bool>
{
    public bool Handle(Query query)
    {
        return query.Value > 0;
    }
}

public class Dispatcher
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> handlers = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public Dispatcher()
    {
        handlers.Add(typeof(Query), new QueryHandler());
    }

    public T Dispatch<T>(IQuery<T> query)
    {
        IQueryHandler<IQuery<T>, T> queryHandler;

        if (!this.handlers.TryGetValue(query.GetType(), out object handler) ||
            ((queryHandler = handler as IQueryHandler<IQuery<T>, T>) == null))
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        return queryHandler.Handle(query);
    }
}
```

And this si how I am calling my code:

```
Query query = new Query();
Dispatcher dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
var result = dispatcher.Dispatch(query);
```

But the problem is that inside the dispatcher, I don't know why the variable handler cannot be casted as `IQueryHandler<IQuery<T>,T>`. Here is some extra data:
[image]

PS: I know how to make this work(with dynamic), but I want to understand why THIS code isn't working.

Comment: which version of C# and the runtime is this? does it support `out` already?

Comment: .net framework 4.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code does not work because `IQueryHandler` is invariant on the `TQuery` generic parameter. `TQuery` needs to be covariant in order for `handler` to be convertible to `IQueryHandler<IQuery<T>, T>`, but that is impossible, as I will explain later. You could however, make `TQuery` contravariant, which allows you to convert `handler` to `IQueryHandler<ASubclassOfQuery, T>`. `TResult` can be covariant though. This is the code to do this:

```
public interface IQueryHandler<in TQuery, out TResult> where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
```

See [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) for more info about generic variances.

As for why `handler` is not `IQueryHandler<IQuery<T>, T>`, let's first suppose that it *is*, which means this code would compile:

```
IQueryHandler<IQuery<T>, T> q = handler;
q.Handle(new MyQuery<T>());
```

where `MyQuery` is defined like this:

```
class MyQuery<T> : IQuery<T> {}
```

However, `handler` is of runtime type `QueryHandler`. `QueryHandler.Handle` only handles `Query` objects, not `MyQuery<T>` objects! We have a contradiction, and hence our assumption that `handler` is a `IQueryHandler<IQuery<T>, T>` must be false.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle for this? I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: @John It's not supposed to work. By adding `in` and `out`, I am suggesting ways to make the code more flexible, but the problem of "`handler` is not `IQueryHandler<IQuery<T>, T>`" cannot be solved. See the second half of the answer for why.

Comment: Ah, I see. Understood.

Answer (score 5):

This is a covariance problem. The real type of `handler` is `QueryHandler`, so it is a `IQueryHandler<Query, bool>`. Of course `Query` is an `IQuery<bool>`, but that is the point of covariance.

It is like trying to assign a `List<String>` to a variable of type `List<Object>`.

There exists an `out` keyword that allows you to use the covariance on your `IQueryHandler` interface as you expect it.

See [out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier) for detailed information

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by [Sweeper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57918963/10310053), you cannot use `out` on `TQuery` because it is used as input parameter. The correct solution is to avoid the dependecy of `QueryHandler` on `Query`. [Isma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57919161/10310053) has shown nicely how it is done.

Comment: Can `TQuery` be covariant though? It is used as an input parameter.

Comment: Ahh no indeed, you are right, I didn't think far enough.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different way to do this to avoid the covariance problem:

```
public interface IQuery<TResult>
{
    TResult Value { get; set; }
}

public interface IQueryHandler<TResult>
{
    TResult Handle<TQuery>(TQuery query) where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>;
}

public class Query : IQuery<bool>
{
    public bool Value { get; set; }
}

public class QueryHandler : IQueryHandler<bool>
{
    public bool Handle<TQuery>(TQuery query) where TQuery : IQuery<bool>
    {
        return query.Value;
    }
}

public class Dispatcher
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> handlers = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public Dispatcher()
    {
        handlers.Add(typeof(Query), new QueryHandler());
    }

    public T Dispatch<T>(IQuery<T> query)
    {
        if (handlers.ContainsKey(query.GetType()))
        {
            var queryHandler = (IQueryHandler<T>)handlers[query.GetType()];
            return queryHandler.Handle(query);
        }

        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Example:

```
var queryHandler = new QueryHandler();
var query = new Query();
query.Value = true;
var dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
dispatcher.Dispatch(query);
>> True
```

Answer (score 0):

Your following line does not makes sense:

```
handler as IQueryHandler<T, T>
```

as the first and second type parameter can never be same as `Query` and `Result` will always be of different types.

You need some mechanism to provide the second type parameter in your `Dispatcher` and one way is this:

```
public class Dispatcher<TResult> 
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> handlers = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public Dispatcher()
    {
        handlers.Add(typeof(Query), new QueryHandler());
    }

    public TResult Dispatch<TQuery>(TQuery query) where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
    {
        IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> queryHandler;

        if (!this.handlers.TryGetValue(query.GetType(), out object handler) ||
            ((queryHandler = handler as IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>) == null))
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        return queryHandler.Handle(query);
    }
}
```

and it can be called like:

```
Query query = new Query();
Dispatcher<bool> dispatcher = new Dispatcher<bool>();
var result = dispatcher.Dispatch(query);
```

Another way around is to take second type parameter in the `Dispatch` method but in my opinion the first way is more better:

```
public class Dispatcher<TQuery, TResult> where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>, new()
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> handlers = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public Dispatcher()
    {
        handlers.Add(typeof(Query), new QueryHandler());
    }

    public TResult Dispatch()
    {
        TQuery query = new TQuery();
        IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> queryHandler;

        if (!this.handlers.TryGetValue(query.GetType(), out object handler) ||
            ((queryHandler = handler as IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>) == null))
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        return queryHandler.Handle(query);
    }
}
```

and calling side will look like:

```
Dispatcher<Query, bool> dispatcher = new Dispatcher<Query,bool>();
var result = dispatcher.Dispatch();
```